# DRYing in JSON responce or request

Tags: json

this is my response

```
[{
    Name: 'Shahrooz',
    family: 'mohseni'
}, {
    Name: 'Jefri',
    family: 'rezaee'
}, {
    Name: 'mjsoft',
    family: 'ali'
}]
```

in each request we transfare Name and family for define json object and this is not dry.in big site is important.
Is there any way for compress json for responce or request?

Comment: Is this an AJAX response in a website or is part of the communication between applications?

Comment: You realize this is not actually valid JSON in the first place, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps you:

- [JSON Compression algorithms](http://web-resource-optimization.blogspot.com/2011/06/json-compression-algorithms.html)
- [RJSON: compress JSON to JSON](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4068383)

in the previous articles two solutions are proposed:

- [HPack](https://github.com/WebReflection/JSONH)
- [RJson](https://github.com/dogada/RJSON)

and **[here](http://www.cliws.com/e/06pogA9VwXylo_GknPEeFA/)** the author recommend rjson on jsonh.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the one defining the protocol, and you don't want to repeat yourself, then… just don't.

For example, you could pass arrays instead of objects, meaning you just pass this:

```
[[
    'Shahrooz',
    'mohseni'
], [
    'Jefri',
    'rezaee'
], [
    'mjsoft',
    'ali'
]]
```

Ideally you'd design the server side to understand both versions, so you could use the more readable one for testing.

Or, a different alternative:

```
{
    'Names': [
        'Shahrooz',
        'Jefri',
        'mjsoft'
    ],
    'Families': [
        'mohseni',
        'rezaee',
        'ali'
    ]
}
```

Or even:

```
{
    'Keys': ['Name', 'Family'],
    'Values': [
        [
            'Shahrooz',
            'mohseni'
        ], [
            'Jefri',
            'rezaee'
        ], [
            'mjsoft',
            'ali'
        ]
    ]
}
```